# Passing parameter and user input

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am trying to pass a few parameter and a user input to a search_form.asp page.

```
<form action="search_form.asp" method="Post">     
    <input type="text"name="fname"/></th>             
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

<a href="search_form3.asp?RecId=<%=registerRS.Fields("id")%>&Lname=%=registerRS.Fields("lname")%>"></a>
```

And on search_form.asp...

```
lname=request.QueryString("Lname")
fname=request.form("fname")
```

But I am unable to see lname when i place `Response.Write("<p>Name: " & lname)` in search_form.asp

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue, this might help. Change <form action="search_form.asp?Lname=<%=registerRS.Fields("lname")%>" method="Post">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not preserved when you submit the form, so search_form.asp will not have a query string.  As an alternative, could you include the query string as a hidden field:

```
 <form action="search_form.asp" method="Post">
      <input type="text"name="fname"/></th>
      <input type="submit" value="Update">
      <input type="hidden" name="lname" value="<%=Request.QueryString("lname")%>" />
  </form>
```

And then refer to `Request.Form("lname")` in search_form.asp.

Alternatively, could you include the query string in the form action?

```
 <form action="search_form.asp?<%=Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")%>" method="Post">
      <input type="text"name="fname"/></th>
      <input type="submit" value="Update">
      <input type="hidden" name="lname" value="<%=Request.QueryString("lname")%>" />
  </form>
```

This should pass the query string on the original page when the form is submitted.